# GWT Event Service Multiple / shared sessions

Tags: events, gwt, service, shared, gwt-eventservice

I build a simple chat with GWT Event Service.
When i open the chat in two tabs of a browser, only one tab catches the event.

I think i can solve this problem by adding this line to the properties:

eventservice.connection.id.generator = de.novanic.eventservice.service.connection.id.SessionExtendedConnectionIdGenerator

Now, only the last tab, i open, catches the events.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is what I did:

```
# Generator for unique client ids
eventservice.connection.id.generator = de.novanic.eventservice.service.connection.id.SessionExtendedConnectionIdGenerator
```

@Marcel Stör: you are probably looking at an older version of gwteventservice http://gwteventservice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/eventservice/src/main/java/de/novanic/eventservice/service/connection/id/SessionExtendedConnectionIdGenerator.java

Answer (score -1):

try this instead

```
# Generator for unique client ids
eventservice.connection.id.generator=de.novanic.eventservice.service.connection.id.SessionExtendedClientIdGenerator
```

the  class name is `SessionExtendedClientIdGenerator` not `SessionExtendedConnectionIdGenerator`

Comment: Huhh? Were did you get that from? There's no such class... Check here: http://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/source/browse/trunk/eventservice/src/main/java/de/novanic/eventservice/service/connection/id/